# My mouse response too fast and sometimes it freeze

Tags: windows-7, mouse, freeze, toshiba-laptop

I have a problem within my laptop mouse. It **respond very fast** for example if i open a site in new tab : 3 tabs or more will open and if i closed a folder and there is other folders behind the main interface they will be closed all.

And sometimes also it **freeze for some seconds** witout any reason.

I have *checked / unchecked the option allow this device to wake up the computer* but didn't work

I have tried to *update / re-install the driver* but i still have the same problem.But also making change in mouse response options : *double click speed : slow <--> fast but still have the same issue*

Nb: My mouse comes from HP invent Rating 5V -- 100mA
Thanks for your help

Comment: Have you tried another mouse?  It's the most common reason to replace a mouse when buttons start to act up like this.  Obviously, if it's a cordless mouse, you should try changing the batteries first.

Comment: @JuliePelletier No it's not a wireless mouse , and the problem doesn't appear with other mouses !

Comment: Then that confirms what I said.  Just replace the malfunctioning mouse.

Comment: Can you please specify the model and manufacturer of the mouse you're using?

Comment: @JuliePelletier yes right ok but the purpose is to work with the existing mouse not to went to buy another mouse

Comment: @alljamin i have updated the post with the info Hp invent

Comment: @Frankenstein:  If you want to fix it, open it open and redo the button soldering.  That's usually what causes this to happen.  Of course it's not worth it but since you ***love*** that mouse so much, that's the only possibility to try.

Answer (score 1):

On your place, before diving into soldering as @julie-pelletier suggests or buying a new mouse as many other suggested, I would consider trying the following steps to recover proper functionality of the mouse:

1. There could be a situation when the mouse sensor what contacts with a surface is not clean. You can clean it with a Dust removal spray.
2. There could be a problem of the mouse contact with the current surface, so you might want to try use it on different surfaces and see if it responds the same.
3. There could be a situation when of connected peripherals may interfere with your mouse. Try disconnecting all the peripherals and see the mouse behavior.
4. The USB port you're using could be damaged. Try to connect your mouse to other available USB ports.
5. The problem also could occur from the OS side. Try getting the latest updates as well as cleaning up your machine with a free version of [CCleaner](https://www.piriform.com/ccleaner/download).

There are more steps provided on [Computer Hope blog](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000253.htm) you might want to look into them if none of the described above steps helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Your mouse is probably malfunctioning and is faulty so the best solution would probably be to get another mouse.

Comment: yes it could the final solution to try